# Contar quantidade de Usuarios

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, expressões-lambda, count

Tenho uma classe Cliente, e uma Classe Sistemas.

Um cliente tem um ou mais sistemas:

```
public class ClienteEmpresa : Pessoa
{

 public virtual ICollection<TipoDeSistemas> TipoDeSistemas { get; set; }
}
```

E a classe sistemas tem um ou muitos Clientes:

```
 public class TipoDeSistemas
    { 
  public virtual ICollection<ClienteEmpresa> ClienteEmpresa { get; set; }
    }
```

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para contar quantos usuarios usam o sistema X.
por exemplo: 
Maria, João, José, e Lurdes, usam o sistema **W**. queria saber como fazer esse count(), usando entity, com expressões labdas.
Alguém para me dar uma dica?

eu fizde um jeito aqui, que ta funcionado.

```
List<TipoDeSistemas> sis = db.TipoDeSistemaDb.ToList();

            var si = sis.Find(c => c.Descricao == "SMC");
            ViewBag.Smc = si.ClienteEmpresa.Count(c => c.StatusCliente == StatusCliente.Ativo);

            var merchant = sis.Find(c => c.Descricao == "MERCHANT");
            ViewBag.Merchantd = merchant.ClienteEmpresa.Count(c => c.StatusCliente == StatusCliente.Ativo);

            var manifestacao = sis.Find(c => c.Descricao == "MANIFESTAÇÃO");
            ViewBag.Manifestacao = manifestacao.ClienteEmpresa.Count(c => c.StatusCliente == StatusCliente.Ativo);

            var cte = sis.Find(c => c.Descricao == "CT-e");
            ViewBag.CTe = cte.ClienteEmpresa.Count(c => c.StatusCliente == StatusCliente.Ativo);
```

Comment: Sugiro adicionar na pergunta o código que você está usando para consultar os dados do banco de dados com o que você já inciou.

Comment: Coloca o código do seu repositório, atualmente você está iterando em uma lista em memória, sendo que nesse caso você pode usar a sintaxe de método (lambda) para gerar um SQL e ser executado direto no seu banco. Assim sua aplicação ganha mais performance.